# Unable to add an RDS instance to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Suddenly I can't add an RDS to my EB environment, not sure why. Here's the full error message:

> Unable to retrieve RDS configuration options.
>
> Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'db.t1.micro' (Namespace: 'aws:rds:dbinstance', OptionName: 'DBInstanceClass'): DBInstanceClass db.t1.micro not supported for mysql db

I am not sure if this is due to the default AMI that I am using or something else.

**Note** that I didn't choose to launch t1.micro RDS instance. Seems like eb is trying to get that but this type has been eliminated from RDS instance class.

Just found this link in the community forum. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=4840, looks like elastic Beanstalk has not updated cloudformation templates yet.

Comment: having the same problem. it seems like ebs removed db.t1.micro, but it also makes it impossible to deploy new environments even if you want other database provider or class

Comment: Check out the edited question at the end, which might explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's resolved now. But as a side note, AWS should not make things like this a community announcement.

Comment: Probably a good idea to put what was the answer in the answer ;)

Comment: AWS resolved it. There was no workaround from user's side.