# Unable Configure Oracle RDS instance in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I want to configure an **Oracle Se instance** on the **elastic beanstalk environment**, and I have chosen the oracle-se from the selection box, but the related select option of version and instance class does not be updated.

I have chosen the db.t2.micro (due to free tier usage), and it shows I have selected the db.m1.small. Then, it keeps prompting the error message when I save that configuration.

For example:

> Unable to retrieve RDS configuration options.
>
> Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value:
> 'db.m1.small' (Namespace: 'aws:rds:dbinstance', OptionName:
> 'DBInstanceClass'): DBInstanceClass db.m1.small not supported for
> oracle-se1 db engine.

[Sample image with related error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcoAG.png)

I have also searched the other stack overflow forum like [Unable to add an RDS instance to Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219668/unable-to-add-an-rds-instance-to-elastic-beanstalk), and those forum has stated that AWS has resolved this problem, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Bundling db with your EB env is  generally not a good practice. Usually you would create rds separately from the EB env. Have you considered that?

Comment: @Marcin Ya, i know it, but i want the oracle database is within the free tier usage, cause currently if created db separately i unable to enjoy the free tier usage with db.t2.micro

Comment: `db.t2.micro` instances are deprecated for oracle, so even if eb console was working I don't think you would be able to use it anyway. If EB console does not work, you can try with AWS CLI or SDK to create it. Have you checked that.